# Calcualted column is returning "#Name?"

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula, formula

I have the following formula for a single line of text Calculated column named `ShowInApp`:

```
IF(OR(Status="Inactive",ISBLANK(Status)),"Hide",IF(FIND("Pending",[Category]),"Hide",IF(FIND("Monitoring And Evaluation Plan",[Category]),"Hide","Show")))
```

But on some cases I will get `#Name?` or `#VALUE!`, as follow:

[image]

Any Advice? Thanks

In short I want to set the calculated column to `Hide`, if any of the following is true:

1. Status is blank
2. Status = inactive
3. Category contain the word Pending
4. Category contain "Monitoring And Evaluation Plan"

Else to set the calculated column to `Show`.

Comment: Do you really need "contain" condition for category or exact "equal to" condition will be fine?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i need contain, as we have statues such as "Pending approval", "pending closure". etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        [Status] = "Inactive",
        ISBLANK([Status])
    ),
    "Hide",
    IF(
        NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Pending", [Category]))),
        "Hide",
        IF(
            NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Monitoring And Evaluation Plan", [Category]))), "Hide", "Show"
        )
    )
)
```

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: worked thanks...